# Name of a theorem about uniform convergence at an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let ${f_n}\left( x \right):\left[ {a,b} \right] \to \mathbf{R} $ be continuous and assume that this sequence convergence uniformly on the open interval $(a,b)$. Then the sequence convergences pointwise at the endpoints: $x=a$ and $x=b$.

Does this theorem have a name?
For some reason I could barely find it mentioned online, even though I find it quite a useful theorem.

Comment: As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459325/f-n-uniformly-convergent-on-open-interval-convergent-at-endpoints) that means than uniform convergence of a sequence of continuous functions on $(a,b)$ implies uniform convergence on $(a,b)$, which I find surprising.

Comment: For the case of power series, this is very similar to Abel's theorem