Uniform convergence on a closed interval
If a series of functions in R is uniformly convergent on an open interval, and point wise convergent on the endpoints, is it uniformly convergent on the closed interval? I feel like it should be, because the max error on the closed set is either the max error of the open set or the error at the endpoint, both of which should be finite and go to zero. However this idea didn't show up in my textbook, despite a similar theorem for uniformly continuity. Is the statement wrong or is it just unimportant/obvious so not in the textbook?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459325

Let $X=A_1\cup \ldots \cup A_k.$ Assume  the series of functions is uniformly convergent on each $A_l$ for $1\le l\le k.$ Then the series is uniformly convergent on $X.$ In your case $[a,b]={a}\cup (a,b)\cup {b}.$
